# Wrap image to top left in div with content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page having content mixed of P, UL IMG etc, I am trying to resize the image via CSS and align the image from top-left positions but when I do this the sometimes the content is overlapping image, sometimes the UL's bullets are out of grid. Please suggest the CSS for this

Here is the working demo on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/7tcbset5/1/)

```
.scrollable_content {
    width: 1140px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.scrollable_content > img {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
.scrollable_content > ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to achieve, and what is exactly your problem?

Comment: I don't see any overlapping on my browser(Firefox 53)

Comment: I am trying to give marking of UL from left, but margin not working..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Chrome browser? can you let us know which browser you use. as i don't see any overlapping on my side

Comment: This should be an comment instead of an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing much overlapping while using chrome. I do see that you have a `width: 1140px;` wich isn't responsive. try using percentages for that instead. See the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7tcbset5/2/). Further i don't have any overlapping items. Hope it helps!